# Can linux cgroups and namespaces assist hiding malware?

Tags: linux, virtualization, rootkits

Reading about sandboxing/security possibilities I was looking a bit into *cgroups* and *namespaces* and asked myself:

How do I know that my linux `root` account is indeed the real `root` account and not simply some sort of faked?

Surely a malware could hideout also in firmware (e.g. x86 SMM based) and kernelspace just as undedected, yet I wanted to assert with the experts here, if my assumption is correct that namespaces and cgroups would make it harder or impossible to know if one is the top-level host root or simply a containerized-fake root?

Similar questions have been with hypervizor rootkits often termed "bluepill" that employ virtualization. Timing-test have been suggested/employed as a tool to acertain infection status.

How is it with namespaces and cgroups, is there a "redbill", a way to know that my `root` is really `root` to the kernel?
What roles can modern linux kernel features like *namespaces* and *cgroups* play?

Comment: I've found out that concept not so far ago, and also wondering if that possible. I think that since this question didn't get any answers -- I believe that it could.